# Android Add View adds only first custom view for arc

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I'm trying to draw a pie chart with each arc as separate custom object. But only first slice of the arc is shown.
LinearLayout does have Vertical orientation as it has been suggested in other posts.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Listing 1 Custom View class (MySliceView.java):**

```
package com.example.piechartsample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MySliceView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private float[] value_degree;
    private int[] COLORS = {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.GRAY, Color.RED, Color.CYAN};
    RectF rectf = new RectF(10, 10, 500, 500);
    float temp = 0;

    float sliceStartAngle, sliceSweepAngle;
    int sliceColor;
    RectF sliceRectf;

    public MySliceView(Context context, float[] values) {

        super(context);
        value_degree = new float[values.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            value_degree[i] = values[i];
        }
    }

    public MySliceView(Context context, RectF rectF, float startAngle, float sweepAngle, int color) {
        super(context);
        sliceRectf = rectF;
        sliceStartAngle = startAngle;
        sliceSweepAngle = sweepAngle;
        sliceColor = color;
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(sliceColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rectf, sliceStartAngle, sliceSweepAngle, true, paint);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), this.getTag().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Listing 2 Layout (activity_slice_view.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliceViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slicePieText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Slice Pie"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Listing 3: Activity class (SliceViewActivity.java):**

```
package com.example.piechartsample;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class SliceViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    float dataValues[] = {300, 400, 100, 500, 200};
    float sweepAngle[] = new float[dataValues.length];
    float startAngle[] = new float[dataValues.length];

    private int[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.GRAY, Color.RED, Color.CYAN};
    RectF rectf = new RectF(10, 10, 500, 500);

    private String TAG = "SliceViewActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slice_view);
        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliceViewLayout);
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        calculateSweepAngle(dataValues);
        calculateStartAngle(sweepAngle);

        MySliceView slice1 = new MySliceView(this, rectf, startAngle[0], sweepAngle[0], colors[0]);
        slice1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        slice1.setTag("Slice1");
        linear.addView(slice1);

        MySliceView slice2 = new MySliceView(this, rectf, startAngle[1], sweepAngle[1], colors[1]);
        slice2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        slice2.setTag("Slice2");
        linear.addView(slice2);

    }

    private void calculateSweepAngle(float[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            total += data[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sweepAngle[i] = 360 * (data[i] / total);
            //Log.d(TAG, "calculateSweepAngle Post Calc Data " + i + ":" + sweepAngle[i]);
        }
    }

    private void calculateStartAngle(float[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float startDegree = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                startDegree += data[i - 1];
            }
            startAngle [i] = startDegree;
            //Log.d(TAG, "calculateStartAngle Post Calc Data " + i + ":" + startAngle[i]);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to do with help of a third party library. Try it
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to get this working without using any libraries. Is there a way?